# Wide Open Throttle transistor switch

Tags: transistors

I bought a car that had a transmission swap, transmission was a bit lazy so i had it scanned. The transmission ecu is looking for a physical Wide Open Throttle(wot)switch that is grounded when the pedal is depressed. What i want to do instead of using a physical switch, is to use a transistor that is grounded when the base signal is above 4 volts, this 4 volts will be taken from a Throttle Position Sensor(TPS) that ranges from about .3v-4.8v. I am not certain but i think the transmission's ecu wot port that will be grounded might have a 5 volt reference with average amp draw of about 1ma - 3ma, the tps signal might be about 1ma-3ma also.

What resistor would i use for R1 and what transistor model would i need? Would i even need a resistor being that the tps in essence is a resistor? Thanks in advance.
[image: sample circuit i drew]

Comment: A simple single transistor circuit is not likely to give you the accuracy & repeatability or sharp switching characteristic you'd need for that. You'd be better off using a voltage comparator or opamp with some hysteresis.

Comment: I agree with @brhans. You could go with six resistors and two BJTs in a long-tailed pair arrangement to get the hysteresis and nice threshold, but even then the output impedance would need adjustment with a third BJT. The nice thing is that this doesn't need a separate power rail -- it can directly work off of the TPS drive itself. But the circuit starts to get annoying with so many parts and the comparator starts looking nicer, especially if you have access to a rail voltage somewhere.

Comment: The TPS sensor has a 5V supply from the ECU going to it, right?

Comment: I thought a email would have been sent when i received a reaponse. I did not know anyone responded. Thanks for the responses. @Th